# include the outptut of storedprocedure in select

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
create proc calcaulateavaerage
@studentid int
as
begin

-- some complicated business and query

return @result  -- single decimal value 
end
```

and then I want to

create proc the whole result

```
select * , ................................ from X where X.value >  (calculateaverage X.Id)
```

It always gives an error that reads like "multi-part identifier calculateaverage couldn't be bound." Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a stored procedure. You want a function.

Comment: What's destroying the performance isn't the function syntax. It's the repeated execution of the "complicated business query" over every record in the table you're calling X. That doesn't go away just because the complicated business query is in a stored procedure.

Consider instead making a view that implements some or all of the business logic. You can SELECT and JOIN to that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use Output variables to output the data out of stored procedure:

```
create proc calcaulateavaerage
@studentid int, @result int
as
begin

-- some complecated business and query

select @result = id from sometable;
end

-- Declaring output variable named result;
declare @result int;
-- Passing output variable to stored procedure.
exec calculateaverage 1, @result;

-- Now you can display the result or do whatever you like.
print @result
```

Comment: Does that accomplish the goal of being able to use the procedure call in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement?